# Bring back first date by product without duplicates

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a member activity table like below:

[image]

In this table although the product names are different, multiple products can be mapped to similar products like below:

[image]

Based on the member activity table, i need to find the first activity date for every member by product. the output would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your mapping is stored in the `mapping` table.

```
select a.member_id,m.mapped_product, min(a.activity_date) as activity_date
from member_activity a 
     inner join (select distinct product, mapped_product from mapping m) m on a.product=m.product 
group by  a.member_id,m.mapped_product
```

Comment: in the query you provided, how is it looking for the min dates between the different m.products? - i.e how is the query looking for min dates between products AFC and AF?

Comment: Join performed first and for products `AFC` and `AF` their corresponding mapped product selected: `A` along with their dates and member: 1/1/2017, member 1 and 1/8/2017, member 2 for `AFC` and 2/1/2017, member 1 for `AF`, totally three rows after JOIN. Then group by selects min(date) for each member and mapped_product: for member 1 and `A` minimum of (`1/1/2017`, `2/1/2017`) = `1/1/2017` and min (`1/8/2017`) = `1/8/2017` for member 2, mapped product 'A'. Note, this will work only if your dates are stored as `date` or 'YYYY-MM-DD' strings. This is important for `min` to work correctly

Comment: Dates should be in correctly sort-able format: year-month-day it should be, not month-day-year or day-month-year.